# Android stopService() not stopping

Tags: android, android-service, ondestroy

This is the code I am running to stop my service that is running in the background. If i push the stop button the service just keeps running. The toast from the onDestroy function runs but the service doen't stop. Anny help?

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), myServices.class));
            //dialContactPhone("123123123");
        }
    });
    Button btnstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), myServices.class));
        }
    });

}
```

This is the code in the service.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,  int flags, int startId) {
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
        // success! we have an accelerometer

        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        vibrateThreshold = accelerometer.getMaximumRange() / 2;
        running = false;
    } else {
        // fai! we dont have an accelerometer!
    }

    //initialize vibration

return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servive stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: If by "the service doen't stop", you mean "the sensor readings keep arriving", that is because you did not unregister your listener in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: yes thats what i mean. How should i unregister the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "the service doen't stop", you mean "the sensor readings keep arriving", that is because you did not unregister your listener in `onDestroy()`. Do that by calling `unregisterListener()` on the `SensorManager` in `onDestroy()`, passing in your listener (which looks like it is `this`).